# SQL Server trigger values error

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, sql-insert

I have this issue. I am new in SQL.

[image]

Comment: Your insert statement is incorrect. It should be Insert Table(Column). You have square brackets where you should have parenthesis. And are you really trying to insert a new row to the audit table with only one single value? That insert will create a new and the ONLY column populated would be LastUodateTime. That seems like not what you want.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code. Post code as properly formatted text, please.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. The column list of an `insert` statement should be denoted with `()`, not with `[]`:

```
INSERT INTO tblAudit (lastUpdateTime)
-- Here -------------^--------------^
VALUES (GETDATE())
```